# Setting up Ruby on Rails App. Problems installing mysql gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to set up rails for the first time. I've got the app made, I've been following lots of guides.

When I try to install the mysql gem `gem install mysql`

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... no
checking for rb_str_set_len()... no
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-config
        --without-mysql-config
```

Looking around on SO and Google, people say to do:

```
gem install mysql --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config
```

but I get:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Comment: what platform are you on? Mac? Linux?

Comment: What distribution? Ubuntu? Debian?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already you'll need to install the MySQL development library as root:

```
yum install mysql-devel
```

Then in the gem install command you need to have another -- in the command line before the --with-mysql-config option:

```
gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config
```

Comment: when I use yum I get: There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   /usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-dynload/datetime.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory

Comment: Yikes.  I Googled that error message and others are getting that same error. It usually indicates an actual memory issue.  This post has a good possible solution:
https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=20849
Run ulimit -m unlimited -d unlimited -v unlimited  to allow unlimited memory.  I'd be careful with setting that though... you might want to check if something else is eating up your memory.

Comment: I'm going to wait before I try that to hear back from the host. They might have more info on what's running. It is a shared host, so it's possible some other user is using large amounts of memory.

Comment: I'm getting `mysql.h is missing` even with `--with-mysql-lib`, and there is no `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/` directory although mysql is working when using xampp.